# Create (pandas / matplotlib) Chart For Each Change In First Column Value - Export All in One PDF

Tags: python

I have data that looks like this:

| ID_Num | Date | Data_1 | Data_2 | Data_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 75 | 49 | 98 |
| 1 | 1/3/2021 | 76 | 99 | 18 |
| 1 | 1/4/2021 | 64 | 54 | 71 |
| 1 | 1/5/2021 | 88 | 60 | 96 |
| 1 | 1/11/2021 | 8 | 40 | 33 |
| 1 | 1/12/2021 | 66 | 71 | 34 |
| 1 | 1/13/2021 | 15 | 49 | 100 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 50 | 55 | 35 |
| 2 | 1/3/2021 | 14 | 10 | 26 |
| 2 | 1/4/2021 | 71 | 37 | 30 |
| 2 | 1/5/2021 | 41 | 36 | 92 |
| 3 | 1/1/2021 | 78 | 59 | 57 |
| 3 | 1/3/2021 | 28 | 58 | 51 |

I want to create a pdf report that has a generated line chart for each "ID_Num" with "Date" on the x axis and "Data_1,Data_2,Data_3" plotted on the y axis. I'd like the report to contain all the graphs in one document.

I'd also like the title of each chart to contain the "ID_Num" that's being plotted

This is where I'm at:

```py
import os
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#needed to see charts in dark theme
from matplotlib import style
style.use('dark_background')

#%% Get data
df = pd.read_excel('/home/james/git/JamesWork/Example_Data.xlsx')
print(df)
#%% Plots 

#charttitle = df.ID_Num + ' - Chart'
plt.figure(figsize=(19,13))
#plt.title(charttitle, fontdict={'fontweight':'bold', 'fontsize':25})

plt.plot(df.Date, df.Data_1, 'g.-', label='Data1')
plt.plot(df.Date, df.Data_2, 'r.-', label='Data2')
plt.plot(df.Date, df.Data_3, 'b.-', label='Data3')

plt.xlabel('Year', fontdict={'fontsize':20})
plt.ylabel('Values', fontdict={'fontsize':20})
plt.ylim([0, None])
plt.legend(prop={'size':20})
plt.savefig('/home/james/git/JamesWork/Code_Exports/test.pdf', dpi = 300)
plt.show()
```

---

EDIT: I'm thinking 1.) delete every pdf in the folder 2.) loop though my data creating a pdf for every "ID_Num" 3.) Merge the PDFs together

I have 1 and 3 figured out:

#1:

```py
#%% Deletes Just PDFs
for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/james/git/JamesWork/Code_Modules/Example'):
    for fn in filenames:
        if fn.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            os.remove(os.path.join(parent, fn))
```

And #3:

```py
#%% Combines PDFS
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
x = [a for a in os.listdir() if a.endswith(".pdf")]
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in x:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it all. Cheers:

```py
import os
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#needed to see charts in dark theme
from matplotlib import style
style.use('dark_background')
#%% Gets data
df = pd.read_excel('/home/james/git/JamesWork/Example_Data.xlsx')
print(df)

#%% Deletes Just PDFs
for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/james/git/JamesWork/Code_Modules/Example_ChartPuller_PDFMerge'):
    for fn in filenames:
        if fn.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            os.remove(os.path.join(parent, fn))

#%% Find Unique Values
IDNumbers = df.ID_Num.unique()
print(IDNumbers)
#cycle though ID_Numbs and chart
for x in range(len(IDNumbers)):
    #filter df
    IDnumber = x+1
    print(IDnumber)
    rslt_df = df.loc[df['ID_Num'] == IDnumber]
    print(rslt_df)
    #plot new df
    #charttitle = rslt_df.ID_Num + ' - Chart'
    plt.figure(figsize=(19,13))
    #plt.title(charttitle, fontdict={'fontweight':'bold', 'fontsize':25})
    plt.plot(rslt_df.Date, rslt_df.Data_1, 'g.-', label='Data1')
    plt.plot(rslt_df.Date, rslt_df.Data_2, 'r.-', label='Data2')
    plt.plot(rslt_df.Date, rslt_df.Data_3, 'b.-', label='Data3')
    plt.xlabel('Year', fontdict={'fontsize':20})
    plt.ylabel('Values', fontdict={'fontsize':20})
    plt.ylim([0, None])
    plt.legend(prop={'size':20})
    path1 = '/home/james/git/JamesWork/Code_Modules/Example_ChartPuller_PDFMerge'
    filename1 = str(x)+'test.pdf'
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(path1,filename1), dpi = 300)
    #plt.show()

#%% Combines PDFS
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
x = [a for a in os.listdir() if a.endswith(".pdf")]
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in x:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
with open("newresult.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```